# force laptop to open camera on HTML5 file input accept image/* capture

Tags: file-io, camera, html5-video

I need my HTML5 app to capture a picture in high-resolution - the **video/getUserMedia/canvas** combination is working but is not providing the required resolution.

Using the **input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>** (or capture="camera") works OK on
mobile-devices (tablets or phones)  - it offers opening the device's camera at least as one of the options (depending on device, browser)

But I want this to happen on my Windows laptop; I tried Firefox, IE and safari - they all open the file dialog, not the laptop's camera (embedded or attached)

Answer (score 1):

The [HTML Media Capture spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/) is not yet implemented by any desktop browser.

Surprisingly the spec does contain an image of how it would work on desktop/macOS:

[image]

Comment: This is still not implemented on desktop browsers ?